# JodaTime get values from period

Tags: java, datetime, date, jodatime

I have two DateTimes, one is the time 'since' and 'now'

What I need, is get the time between then.

My problem is into the format I want to get it:

Example:
since = '17 april 2010'
now = '15 april 2011'

I want to have '0 years, 11 months, 29 days'

And in case since is '13 april 2010' the result should be like:
'1 years, 0 months, 2 days'

But this logic is puzzling me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I follow your question. It sounds like you want:

```
DateTime since = ...;
DateTime now = ...;

Period period = new Period(since, now, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
int years = period.getYears();
int months = period.getMonths();
int days = period.getDays();
```

If that isn't the case, could you give more details?

Comment: Hmm.. this solves something, just another question, it's month are 0 based? A date from 11 months ago tell me theres only 10.

Comment: Dis-consider it, I put the wrong month in since. Thanks, it's works.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

Quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

1. Use [`Period#between`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#between-java.time.LocalDate-java.time.LocalDate-) to get the period between two `LocalDate`s.
2. Note that the month name in your string is in lowercase and therefore, you will need to build the `DateTimeFormatter` using `parseCaseInsensitive` function.
3. [Never use `DateTimeFormatter` without a `Locale`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                .appendPattern("d MMMM uuuu")
                                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        LocalDate since = LocalDate.parse("17 april 2010", dtf);
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.parse("15 april 2011", dtf);
        
        Period period = Period.between(since, now);
        
        String strPeriod = String.format("%d years %d months %d days", period.getYears(), period.getMonths(),
                period.getDays());
        System.out.println(strPeriod);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0 years 11 months 29 days
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/HAjwMp)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>